# ServiceStack - Returning HttpStatus to Android Device

Tags: c#, android, rest, servicestack

I've been usng ServiceStack to create a REST service that an Android device can communicate with - so far so good, I can POST a DTO to the rest service and it successfully saves... the trouble I'm having is sending back a return status to notify the android app of what happened!

```
ResponseEntity <HttpStatus> responseEntity = restTemplate
                    .exchange (requestUrl,
                               HttpMethod.POST,
                               requestEntity,
                               HttpStatus.class);
/* Never gets to this bit, always throws a runtime exception */
Log.i (TAG, "responseEntity.getStatusCode () --> '" + responseEntity.getStatusCode () + "'");
return responseEntity.getStatusCode ();
```

And my C# code for the rest service is...

```
public object Post(RegisteredDeviceDto registeredDeviceDto)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("RegisteredDeviceRestService::POST::RegisteredDeviceDto (RegisteredDeviceAdd)");
    if (registeredDeviceDto != null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("DeviceToAdd:" + registeredDeviceDto.ToString());
        RegisteredDeviceDomainObject registeredDeviceToAdd =
        _DtoToDomainObject.registeredDeviceDtoToDomainObject(registeredDeviceDto);

        _RegisteredDeviceDao.saveDomainObject(registeredDeviceToAdd);
        return new HttpResult(new object (), "JSON", HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

Even when just using a simple "return HttpStatus.OK" I still get a runtime exception in my android app, yet everything goes to the server and is saved fine... kinda stumped how I'm having trouble with a response code just :P

As always, any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Forgot to mention - I am using the Spring Framework for Android as my Rest provider!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with Android or Spring but my guess is there is an issue with how your ServiceStack response is being converted/deserialized into the Android/Spring `ResponseEntity <HttpStatus>`. HttpStatus looks like an ENUM and, if I understand the documentation here -http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html- it looks like your trying to convert the response body into an HttpStatus ENUM. Maybe try `ResponseEntity<String>`?

Comment: Yeah I think I've tried that as well but I was just getting an empty string.. sort of new to the REST stuff and Spring so no doubt it's something really silly I am doing!

Comment: Yep changing it to String worked, and I was able to get the status code and the response headers from the ResponseEntity :)

Comment: Also turns out in the C# side of things, with ServiceStack I had to use "base.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict;" to change the response code, now in the Android side I can get that status code from the response headers